# onDelete Cascade two sides

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel Framework, I have multiple connected tables, I successfully could remove a operation from `operations` table when the related transaction is deleted from `transactions` table, but i couldn't get it to work in the opposite side, as it throws an error on migration and also when adding new rows to `operations` table.

```
Schema::create('operations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('car_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('operation');
            $table->integer('transaction')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::table('operations', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('transaction')->references('id')->on('transactions')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

What I need is to also delete the transaction when a related operation is deleted:

```
Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('status')->index();
            $table->date('date')->index();
            $table->string('user_added');
            $table->string('note')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    Schema::table('transactions', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('id')->references('transaction')->on('operations')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

For now it throws an error on migration:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
>   constraint (SQL     : alter table `transactions` add constraint
>   `transactions_id_foreign` foreign key (`i     d`) references
>   `operations` (`transaction`) on delete cascade)

Which is normal because `operations` table comes after `transactions` in order, even if i put the second part of the code in `operations` table, it throws a similar error when i start inserting rows to table.

I appreciate leading me to a solution.

Comment: It's a chicken-and-egg problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838010/two-way-foreign-key-constraint-in-a-11-relation

Answer (score 0):

its looks like you added your primarykey as foreignkey

```
Schema::table('transactions', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('id')->references('transaction')->on('operations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

please adding 1 column on transaction table "operations_id" and change your schema like this

```
Schema::table('transactions', function($table) {
$table->foreign('operations_id')->references('id')->on('operations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I avoided that, `transactions` table is not only for operations, there are a lot of things saved in transactions and related to things like operations, i can't open a `something_id` for everything. I'm looking for a better efficient way.